# Set different values of a variable for generated targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am attempting to create a makefile that generates a target for each file in a directory.  Each file would include a list of makefile variable assignments that would then be used by the generated target.

I have it generating targets using `eval`.  I can get the targets to `@echo`.  When I attempt to assign a variable in the file to be used in the target, I don't get what I want.  I want it to have the value from the file.  I can only figure out how to get the value from the last file or the previous file.

This gives the value of stuff from the previous file:

```
myvar = $(sort $(basename $(wildcard *.txt)))

.PHONY: all $(myvar)
all: $(myvar)

define target_template =
 stuff := 
 -include $(1).txt
 $(1): ; @echo target $$@ stuffs $(stuff)
endef

$(foreach v,$(myvar),$(eval $(call target_template,$(v))))
```

This gives me the value from the last file:

```
myvar = $(sort $(basename $(wildcard *.txt)))

.PHONY: all $(myvar)
all: $(myvar)

define target_template =
 stuff := 
 -include $(1).txt
 $(1): ; @echo target $$@ stuffs $$(stuff)
endef

$(foreach v,$(myvar),$(eval $(call target_template,$(v))))
```

Each text file has this content:

```
stuff += mytest<X>
```

Where `<X>` is unique per file.  Note that I am using `+=` because there may be cases where the included text file includes another file which also adds things to the variable.

Is there a way to get it so that the generated target uses the value of `stuff` from the associated text file?

---

I changed the code to this, and it appears to work.  Is this something that I shouldn't do?

```
myvar = $(sort $(basename $(wildcard *.txt)))

.PHONY: all $(myvar)
all: $(myvar)

define target_template =
 $(1):
    $(eval stuff = )
    $(eval include $(1).txt)
    @echo target1 $$@ stuffs $(stuff)
    $(warning $(stuff))
endef

$(foreach v,$(myvar),$(eval $(call target_template,$(v))))
```

---

While my solution works, I agree that the accepted solution is better.  I am leaving my solution as an example of a worse way to do things.

Comment: I prefer @Beta 's solution. Make code in then-empty recipe lines is better avoided. `$(eval` generally is to be avoided if there is an equivalently short alternative. Moreover, the `$(warning )` is AFAIK executed **before** your recipe is handed over to the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what version of Make you're using, but give this a try:

```
define target_template =
 stuff := 
 -include $(1).txt
 stuff_$(1):= $$(stuff)
 $(1): ; @echo target $$@ stuffs $$(stuff_$(1))
endef
```

Comment: I am using GNU Make.  When I use your code, other than the `_$(1)` on the next to last line, I get the variable value from the last file.

Comment: I see how I messed this up when I first looked at it.  Thanks for the answer.